# alert grails pagination current offset value

Tags: grails, pagination

I am using Grails 2.4.2. I have a list which is using pagination. When I mouse hover a number or next page icon it shows current offset number as tool tip. Can I alert this offset number or get my list's current page offset number?

Comment: Try `"${params.offset ?: 0}"`

Comment: it's working thanks a lot. but is there any way that i can pass it through `<g:link></g:link>` to controller? Other wise it will not come to any work

Comment: i tried it in the link but page loading error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
"${params.offset ?: 0}"
```

and pass this to controller, like

```
<g:link controller="someCtrl" action="someActn" params="[offset: params.offset ?: 0]"></g:link>
```